# Memory leakage in library

Tags: memory, c++-cli

I have C++/CLI library compiled with **/clr**.

```
ref class MyClass
{
private:
     array<int>^ d;
public:
     MyClass()
     {

       int size=10000000;
       d=gcnew array<int>(size);
       for(int x=0;x<size;x++)
       {
           d[x]=x;
       };
     };
    ~MyClass()
    {

        MessageBox::Show(gcnew String(L"Disposed"));
    };
    protected:
    !MyClass()
    {
    MessageBox::Show(gcnew String(L"Finalized"));
    };
};

static MyClass^ Test()
{             
     MyClass^ mc = gcnew MyClass();
      //msclr::auto_handle<MyClass^> mc = gcnew MyClass();//this shows error
      //msclr::auto_handle<MyClass> mc = gcnew MyClass();//this either shows error
      //due to return type of function Test()


    return mc;
 };
```

When I use this method and it goes out of scope it should show "Disposed" and release memory.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        MyDll.MyClass mc= MyDll.Test();
 }
```

Unfortunatelly it doesn't do that. Memory is releasing only after application exit by executing Finalizer. How to properly release this memory?

Answer (score 2):

You can use *stack semantics* in C++/CLI to get the compiler to automatically create and dispose the object.  Very similar to native C++:

```
static void Test() {             
     MyClass mc;
}
```

Note the missing ^ hat and the need to *not* return a disposed object.  In your original snippet it must be done by the caller explicitly:

```
static void RunTest() {
    MyClass^ obj = MyClass::Test();
    delete obj;
}
```

Last but certainly not least, do note that there is no point in doing this at all.  A destructor and finalizer is only required to release unmanaged resources.  The garbage collector already releases the MyClass object automatically.  No need to help, nor should you ever try to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic delete in C++ or C++/cli for pointers allocated with new or gcnew. You have to call delete, or in your case (I assume 'mc' is in a C# assembly) mc.Dispose(). Without an explicit dispose it is left to the GC to finalize it.

Note: A call to new (I exclude gcnew, here) without a call to delete is a memory leak.

Comment: How to dispose `array<AnyClass^>^ obj = gcnew array<AnyClass^>(size);`?

Comment: Why `GC.Collect();` command  after dispose doesn't invoke automatically?

Comment: It is .NET: To dispose things you have to call Dispose, otherwise the garbage collector finalize the allocation at some point of time (Balancing performance and memory management somehow). To dispose an array of objects you have to loop through the array and dispose each element.